# Xamarin form pangesture drag and drop flickering

Tags: xamarin.forms, drag-and-drop, frame, draggable, uipangesturerecognizer

What I want is to create a box that I can drag around the screen, so I created a class that extend `Frame` (but it could be also an `AbsoluteLayout`, NOT a `BoxView` because I need to write something inside that box).

CLASS DragBox

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace PanGesture
{
    public class DragBox : Frame
    {
        public DragBox()
        {
            var panGesture = new PanGestureRecognizer();
            this.GestureRecognizers.Add(panGesture);
            panGesture.PanUpdated += OnPanUpdated;
            BorderColor = Color.Blue;
            Padding = 4;
            BackgroundColor = Color.Green;
            Content = new Label
            {
                Text = "Word",
            };
        }

        private void OnPanUpdated(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.StatusType)
            {
                case GestureStatus.Started:
                    Debug.WriteLine("DEBUG: start dragging");
                    break;
                case GestureStatus.Running:
                    this.TranslationX = e.TotalX;
                    this.TranslationY = e.TotalY;
                    break;
                case GestureStatus.Completed:
                    Debug.WriteLine("DEBUG: drag ended");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in the homepage I just create an instance of DragBox
(container is the reference to the `AbsoluteLayout` on the main page

```
public partial class HomePage : ContentPage
{
    public HomePage ()
    {
       InitializeComponent ();
       DragBox box = new DragBox();
       AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(box, new Rectangle(0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2));
       AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(box, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);
       container.Children.Add(box);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I start to drag the box, it has that effect of flickering as you can see in the image below.
How to solve that? Or are there any other way to create a draggable element?

[image]

Comment: Did you try a real device? This might just be a simulator thing.

Comment: @AndresCastro yes and it does the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use your code but I don't have the same issue as you, so I suggest you can try the following code in OnPanUpdated event.

```
private double  _xOffset, _yOffset;

 private void OnPanUpdated(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.StatusType)
        {
            case GestureStatus.Started:
                
                Debug.WriteLine("DEBUG: start dragging");
                break;
            case GestureStatus.Running:

               
                this.TranslationX = _xOffset + e.TotalX;
                this.TranslationY = _yOffset + e.TotalY;
               
                break;
            case GestureStatus.Completed:

                _xOffset = this.TranslationX;

                _yOffset = this.TranslationY;
               

                Debug.WriteLine("DEBUG: drag ended");
                break;
        }
    }
```

**Update:**

I think you may have some issue in PanContainer, please modify you code as follows:

```
public class PanContainer : ContentView
{
   
    private double x, y;
    public PanContainer()
    {
        var panGesture = new PanGestureRecognizer();
        
        panGesture.PanUpdated += OnPanUpdated;
        this.GestureRecognizers.Add(panGesture);                          
    }

    private void OnPanUpdated(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.StatusType)
        {
            case GestureStatus.Started:
                
                Debug.WriteLine("DEBUG: start dragging");
                break;
            case GestureStatus.Running:
                
                Content.TranslationX = x + e.TotalX;
                Content.TranslationY = y + e.TotalY;

                break;
            case GestureStatus.Completed:
            
                x = Content.TranslationX;
                y = Content.TranslationY;

                Debug.WriteLine("DEBUG: drag ended");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Then ContentPage.cs:

```
 public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
{
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Label label = new Label() { Text = "Hello world" ,BackgroundColor=Color.Green, WidthRequest=100,HeightRequest=150};
        PanContainer box = new PanContainer();
        box.Content = label;
       
        container.Children.Add(box);
    }
}
```

You can not drag and drop PanContainer, you just can move PanContainer's content, like this:

[image]

Comment: Nope same effect :(

Comment: @Poli97, please see my update, if my reply help you, please remember to mark my reply as answer, thanks.

Comment: ok thanks now the drag works fine but one more thing, when I release the drag, to drag it again I have to press on the original starting position of the box, if I press where i dropped it it doesn't move, as if his ""frame"" doesn't move, how to fix that?

Comment: @Poli97,I have the same effect at my side, I seems that the Content.x and Content.Y don't still have the original position, you can print `Console.WriteLine("x = " +Content.X + "y = " + Content.Y);` to see, but I try to change content.x, but it seems impossible to change.

Comment: Mmm ok so how is it possible to improve a correct drag and drop function in a Xamarin Forms application? Do you know any other way to do it correctly? Anyway, I starred your reply as answer, as you solved my first problem, so thank you anyway for your time, but please, if you know something else about performing correctly drag and drop in Xamarin Form, please tell me, I really need it for my university thesis. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the TranslateX and TranslateY, use the LayoutTo method like below.

```
private void OnPanUpdated(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
   switch (e.StatusType)
   {
      case GestureStatus.Started:
          break;
      case GestureStatus.Running:
          var newRectangle = new Rectangle(e.TotalX, e.TotalY, this.Bounds.Width, this.Bounds.Height);
          this.LayoutTo(newRectangle, easing: Easing.Linear);
          break;
      case GestureStatus.Completed:
         break;
    }
}
```

Now there is no flickering.

Comment: With that the flickering has gone but now the animation got like a delay and it is not coherent with the movement of my finger